# jQuery DataTable doesn't load array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, datatable

I have a jQuery DataTable. I build the data dynamically using an array of objects. The table doesn't load the data.

Data source:

```
var tableData = [];
tableData.push({"groupName": "CASINOVI-LMSUTESTA"});
```

My jQuery DataTable:

```
var table_dmt = $("#detailsMobileTable").DataTable({
  "language": {
    search: '',
    searchPlaceholder: "Search",
    lengthMenu: "_MENU_",
    paginate: {
      first: `<i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>`,
      previous: `<i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>`,
      next: `<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>`,
      last: `<i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>`
    }
  },
  lengthMenu: [
    [10, 25, 50, 100],
    ['10 entries', '25 entries', '50 entries', '100 entries']
  ],
  "filter": true,
  "bFilter": false,
  "bInfo": false,
  "bPaginate": true,
  "bInfo": true,
  "paging": true,
  "searching": true,
  "data": tableData,
  columns: [{
    data: 'groupName'
  }]
});
```

Perhaps table working as expected with this way of array initialization:

```
var tableData = [{"groupName": "CASINOVI-LMSUTESTA"}];
```

Comment: Have you verified the array has data? Did it go into the for loop that is pushing in the data?

Comment: My guess is you are not showing an asynchronous call to get the data. What does your actual code look like?

Comment: hello @epascarello, the problem is that the table does not show the data when the array is built dynamically, adding objects to it. However it works when I initialize the array directly.

Comment: So how are you actually building it? You had code that showed a loop. What is the actual code.

Comment: yes the code as posted works fine.  the problem is in code we dont have.

Comment: Your code [works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYsMK.png). I cannot recreate the issue.

Comment: You can provide a runnable [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365) to show how to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var tableData = [{"groupName": "CASINOVI-LMSUTESTA"}];
```

Not sure at what point your doing tableData.push but it might cause some timing issues